# Downgrade nvidia driver on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.10

I want to downgrade the nvidia drivers from 435 to 430 or 418, because the 435 (and the 440) does not seems to work with uswsusp to suspend to disk and ram. I did:

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
```

But it does not seems to work:

```
root@is241395:~# apt install nvidia-driver-430
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-gtk3 guile-2.2-libs
  libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5
  libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libcurl4 libdazzle-1.0-0 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevent-2.1-6 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2
  libgc1c2 libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrilo-0.3-0 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 liblua5.3-0 libminiupnpc17 libmspub-0.1-1
  libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.14-0 libqqwing2v5 libraw19 librevenge-0.0-0 librsync2 libsgutils2-2 libsuitesparseconfig5 libvncclient1 libwinpr2-2 libxmlsec1
  libxmlsec1-nss lp-solve media-player-info python3-bcrypt python3-fasteners python3-future python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-mako python3-markupsafe
  python3-monotonic python3-paramiko syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy usb-creator-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-common-430 libnvidia-compute-430 libnvidia-decode-430 libnvidia-encode-430 libnvidia-fbc1-430 libnvidia-gl-430 libnvidia-gl-430:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-430 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-430 nvidia-dkms-430 nvidia-kernel-common-430 nvidia-kernel-source-430 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-430 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-common-430 libnvidia-compute-430 libnvidia-decode-430 libnvidia-encode-430 libnvidia-fbc1-430 libnvidia-gl-430 libnvidia-gl-430:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-430 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-430 nvidia-dkms-430 nvidia-driver-430 nvidia-kernel-common-430 nvidia-kernel-source-430
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-430 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/86,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 395 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64.
(Reading database ... 168652 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libnvidia-cfg1-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-common-430.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libnvidia-common-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-compute-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libnvidia-compute-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-decode-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libnvidia-decode-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-decode-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-encode-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libnvidia-encode-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-encode-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libnvidia-fbc1-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libnvidia-gl-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-gl-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libnvidia-gl-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-430:i386 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libnvidia-ifr1-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libnvidia-ifr1-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-compute-utils-430.
Preparing to unpack .../10-nvidia-compute-utils-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-compute-utils-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-430.
Preparing to unpack .../11-nvidia-kernel-source-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-common-430.
Preparing to unpack .../12-nvidia-kernel-common-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-dkms-430.
Preparing to unpack .../13-nvidia-dkms-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-utils-430.
Preparing to unpack .../14-nvidia-utils-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-utils-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430.
Preparing to unpack .../15-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-430.
Preparing to unpack .../16-nvidia-driver-430_430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../17-nvidia-prime_0.8.13_all.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.13) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../18-nvidia-settings_440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.13) ...
Setting up libnvidia-compute-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-decode-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-common-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-430:i386 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-utils-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Warning: The home dir /nonexistent you specified can't be accessed: No such file or directory
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 125) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 132) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 125) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/nonexistent'.
Setting up libnvidia-encode-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-kernel-common-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Loading new nvidia-430.64 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-24-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.3.0-24-generic
Error! Application of patch do-not-call-pci_save_state.patch failed.
Check /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/430.64/build/ for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-430 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-430 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 6
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-430:
 nvidia-driver-430 depends on nvidia-dkms-430 (= 430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-430 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-430 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-24-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-430
 nvidia-driver-430
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and:

```
root@is241395:~# nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

What is wrong with that?

Many thanks!

Comment: You first posted that you tried installing Nvidia v418 (with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418`), but then you post the (failed) results of installing v430 (with `apt install nvidia-driver-430`). Which one is it???

Comment: Try `sudo apt purge nvidia*`  followed by `sudo apt autoremove`  Then try again. (your posted command purge nvidia. * doesn't match any packages, nvidia* doesn't match all the nvidia driver packages, hence the autoremove) If still getting error on that patch then contact ppa maintainers

Comment: @ajgringo619: I tried both. I eddited the post to make it clearer

Comment: `sudo apt purge nvidia*` followed by `sudo apt autoremove` didn't make it...

Answer (score 1):

418 package is a transitional package to 430, you cannot install 418 anymore that way, please add your voice here to hope for a fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418/+bug/1838875

Meanwhile, you can try to download the driver from here : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418/418.56-0ubuntu1/+build/16531953 and install all the 418 packages using

```
cd /tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/amd64/libnvidia-cfg1-418/418.56-0ubuntu1
wget $NEXTURL
wget $AndSoOn
sudo dpkg -i ./*nvi*
```

Comment: is this true for 440 -> 430 as well?  it seems 440 is breaking something but when i try to install 430 it wants to install 440 all over again.

Comment: It seems so, and now 440 -> 450 as well.